# d3.js Plotting time-graph with lines and circles

Tags: d3.js, graph, time-series

I try to plot some temperatures

```
2018-09-14 00:07:26 16.44
2018-09-14 00:17:27 16.44
2018-09-14 00:27:27 16.38
... etc
```

I do the traditonal graph (scale x and y axis etc) and then plot the temperatures with a line

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.time); })
        .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.temp); });
```

This works ok.

Now i try to plot the temperature with small circles with

```
var my_circle = svg.selectAll(".temp-dot")
        .data(data).enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", ".temp-dott")
        .style("fill", "#FF0000")
        .attr("r", 20.0)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.time); } )
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.temp); } );
```

But this don't work... All circles end upp att 0,0 - Why?

/gh

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Create a reproducible example.  The code presented here is correct and your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: there is a small difference in the class searched and class set `t`